# TeX Live 2012 - what should be known about it?

Tags: texlive

TeX Live 2012 release is near, so I think it is possibly a good time to sum it a bit, like it was done before with [2011](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21994/5264). Feel free to add anything relevant in this community wiki.

**What should we know about TeX Live 2012?**

E.g. As a debian user I'm happy that wheezy (aka testing atm, [freeze is planned on June 30](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/06/msg00006.html)) has the new TeX Live on board since May.

Comment: To avoid any charges: I've already flagged the question for making it a community wiki. Unfortunately I don't see where I can do it myself. I believe I could easily set it year ago. Apparently something changed at TeX.SX.

Comment: TL 2012 contains new versions of XeTeX and LuaTeX, fixing some long-standing bugs. (Not an answer, because I don't want to dig for links right now.)

Comment: @przemoc The ability for the questioner to make a question CW was taken out of the SE system a while back.  What you did is right: flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: Why was it taken out?

Comment: @Ingo: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 27):

The TEX Live Guide for TeX Live 2012 has in section 9 “Release history” following information about the present version (page 39):

> `tlmgr` supports updates from multiple network repositories. The section
>   on multiple repositories in the `tlmgr` help output has more.
>
> The parameter `\XeTeXdashbreakstate` is set to `1` by default, for both
>   `xetex` and `xelatex`. This allows line breaks after em-dashes and
>   en-dashes, which has always been the behavior of plain TeX, LaTeX,
>   LuaTeX, etc. Existing XeTeX documents which must retain perfect
>   line-break compatibility will need to set `\XeTeXdashbreakstate` to `0`
>   explicitly.
>
> The output files generated by `pdftex` and `dvips`, among others, can now
>   exceed 2gb.
>
> The 35 standard PostScript fonts are included in the output of `dvips`
>   by default, since so many different versions of them are extant.
>
> In the restricted `\write18` execution mode, set by default, `mpost` is
>   now an allowed program.
>
> A `texmf.cnf` file is also found in `../texmf-local`, e.g.,
>   `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/texmf.cnf`, if it exists.
>
> The `updmap` script reads a per-tree `updmap.cfg` instead of one global
>   config. This change should be invisible, unless you edited your
>   `updmap.cfg`'s directly. The `updmap` ­help output has more.
>
> Platforms: armel-linux and mipsel-linux added; sparc-linux and
>   i386-netbsd are no longer in the main distribution, but are available
>   for installation as custom binaries, along with a variety of other
>   platforms: http://tug.org/texlive/custom-bin.html.

"Known issues in TeX Live 2012" adds:

> We forgot to mention a notable change in TL 2012: the Japanese uptex
>   engine (Unicode-enhanced ptex) and related programs (uplatex,
>   upbibtex, etc.) are now included.

Comment: There are also a few bug fixes in XeTeX, as far as I know. Maybe @KhaledHosny can be more precise.

Comment: XeLaTeX suddenly allowing line-breaks after n-dashes (undesirable imo) puzzled me quite a bit – thanks for clarifying. But even after turning this off, I still get different hyphenations in my files (some better, some worse than TL '11). Can anyone point me to where I can read more about the changes in hyphenation-rules?

Comment: Is there any list of interesting new packages maybe?

Comment: The XeTeX-SyncTeX bug appears to be fixed as well as of 2012. In previous version there was an wrong offset, causing the sync to occur at a wrong paragraph.