# lualatex and line breaks after em-dashes

Tags: line-breaking, luatex, punctuation

I’ve just installed TeX Live 2012. As mentioned [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60965/) on this site, the release history explains that “the parameter \XeTeXdashbreakstate is set to 1 by default, for both xetex and xelatex. This allows line breaks after em-dashes and en-dashes, which has always been the behavior of plain TEX, LATEX, LuaTEX, etc.”

I rarely use xetex; I’ve worked almost exclusively with luatex since the release of  TeX Live 2011. The only frequent problem I had was that I did *not* get line breaks after em-dashes, and now in 2012 I’m still not getting them, unless I refrain from using the Unicode character — which certainly seems against the spirit of luatex.

Consider this example, where the same paragraph is typed 3 times, with the em-dashes entered differently in each:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature={protrusion=default}]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\pdfprotrudechars=2
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

% Will Robertson’s macro from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34608/
\DeclareRobustCommand\dash{%
 \unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\allowbreak\thinspace\ignorespaces}

\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfinfo{/Title (Jeeves Takes Charge) /Author (P.G. Wodehouse)}
\begin{document}
% using ---
Now, touching this business of old Jeeves---my man, you know---how do we
stand? Lots of people think I’m much too dependent on him. My Aunt
Agatha, in fact, has even gone so far as to call him my keeper. Well,
what I say is: Why not? The man’s a genius. From the collar upward he
stands alone.

% typing the em-dash (easy in utf-8 locale with compose key)
Now, touching this business of old Jeeves—my man, you know—how do we
stand? Lots of people think I’m much too dependent on him. My Aunt
Agatha, in fact, has even gone so far as to call him my keeper. Well,
what I say is: Why not? The man’s a genius. From the collar upward he
stands alone.

% using Will Robertson’s macro
Now, touching this business of old Jeeves\dash my man, you know\dash how do we
stand? Lots of people think I’m much too dependent on him. My Aunt
Agatha, in fact, has even gone so far as to call him my keeper. Well,
what I say is: Why not? The man’s a genius. From the collar upward he
stands alone.
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of compiling the example above with lualatex]

I’ve experimented with various free and commercial fonts, always with the same result.

Is there some luatex equivalent to \XeTeXdashbreakstate which I could set?

Comment: That is the expected behavior, when you use `---` it is treated as a ligature of hyphens and thus have line breaks like hyphen, but not with the Unicode character. In XeTeX `---` was being mapped to the Unicode character, so there was no breaks in both cases.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Expected by the developers, I suppose you mean, because it’s surprising to users. I always thought of `---` as a mere convenience, as a way to get an em-dash even if stuck in an ASCII environment.  I didn’t realize that `---` was a sort of super-em-dash, an em-dash plus other nice features which don’t belong to em-dashes as such.

Comment: I’m not saying it is a desired behavior, I’m just saying it is not a bug, may be a mis feature, lack of feature but not a bug.

Comment: The line breaking with `---` is merely a side effect of the way it is implemented in TeX; a ligature of hyphens, try entering it directly in legacy TeX (`\char124 ` with Computer Modern), no line breaks.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Thank you for these explanations, and thank you also for the many good things you make available on your GitHub page.

Comment: @Thérèse: Somebody must have tweaked something in one of the relevant packages since your question. I am using MikTeX 2.9, reinstalled within the last few weeks, with all packages freshly downloaded from the MikTeX repository. When I ran your MWE as LuaLaTeX in TeXworks, your first and third examples now output with only normal protrusion, instead of the excessive overhangs you got last year. Your second example still has everything welded together, though, like peanut-brittle that's been sitting out on a humid day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what the *correct* answer is. The UTF-8 emdash is considered part of the word. You see this (when you leave out microtype) in the log file:

```
Overfull \hbox (19.42857pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--33
[][]\EU2/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/n/10.95 Now, touch-ing this busi-ness of old Jeeves
—my man, you know—how
```

I am not sure if TeX is able at all to decompose the words when it encounters a character such as `emdash`. So my answer would be "it's not possible".

What you can do, it's slightly a hack:

```
\catcode`\—=13
\protected\def—{\unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\allowbreak\thinspace\ignorespaces}
```

This makes the emdash active and inserts a "breakable" emdash.

Another possibility would be to filter the emdash in a LuaTeX callback and replace it with something breakable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better `\protected\def—{\dash}` (where `\dash` is defined as in the question)? Or just adding `\protected` in front of `\def`, of course.

Comment: @egreg probably. I have no idea what the `\protected` does, but I trust you :)

Comment: It makes (Lua)TeX write the `–` character instead of its expansion in auxiliary files, for instance.

Comment: @Patrick it behaves like `\unexpanded` in ConTeXt.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick and egreg.  I’m quite content to have a bit of a hack in my preamble in exchange for pure Unicode in the body of the document.  But how very odd that the UTF-8 em-dash is considered part of the word, when its grammatical function — at least in the languages I speak — is to set phrases off from the surrounding words rather than to join words.

Comment: @Thérèse well, that's TeX...

Comment: One drawback of this approach is that you always get a good break-point *before* the em-dash; when an em-dash is used to mark the end of a sub-sentence---as this example illustrates---the break-point should be after the em-dash. So, the solution will be to make `.` an active character and use different definitions for odd and even em-dashes in each sentence (just kidding `:-)`).

Comment: @Aditya I don't see any break point before the dash.

Comment: @egreg You are right. I misread the question and the answer! Sorry.

Comment: If one does not want to see spaces, even thin ones, bookending all their emdashes (considered incorrect by many), a `\negthinspace` can be added immediately after each `\thinspace` in your code, resulting in a normal-looking, unspaced, breakable emdash. I put this in my preamble and it works perfectly.

Comment: In a related discussion [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149895/luatex-wont-end-a-line-at-unicode-emdash/150024#150024), the suggestion given above has been further refined to a simple \catcode`\—=13 `\protected\def—{\nobreak\textemdash\allowbreak}`, more simply and directly producing an unspaced, end-breakable emdash.

Answer (score 7):

Imho from the unicode view there shouldn't be automatically a break point after such dashes. With unicode you should probably insert a Zero Width Space (U+200B). It doesn't work out-of-the-box with lualatex, you need something like `luaunicodespace` (https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaunicodespace):

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua {
require('luaunicodespace')
luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", luaunicodespace.handler, "luaotfload", 1)
luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter",         luaunicodespace.handler, "luaotfload", 1)
}
\textwidth=3cm
\begin{document}
Text—Text—Text—Text—Text—Text—Text—Text

Text—^^^^200bText—^^^^200bText—^^^^200bText—^^^^200bText—^^^^200bText—^^^^200bText—^^^^200bText

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike.  I didn’t know about the zero width space, and it’s fairly easy to insert in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

See the last paragraph here: http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/TeX-Live-Jahrgang-2012-1634828.html, you have to set the parameter \XeTeXdashbreakstate to null explicitly starting TeX 2012.

Comment: I’m using luatex, not xetex, and I want line breaks after em-dashes; the result shown in the second paragraph of the image is what I object to.