# Biber failed to identify author name with "-"

Tags: biblatex, biber

When the author name with "-", biber tends to generate dummy characters around the name. For example, one input in bib file as the following.

```
@article{Baker,
author = {Baker, F.B. and Al‐Karni, A},
journal = {Journal of Educational Measurement},
pages = {147--162},
title = {{A comparison of two procedures for computing IRT equating coefficients}},
url = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1745-3984.1991.tb00350.x/abstract},
volume = {28},
year = {1991}
}
```

when the above input compiled in latex, error message will be generated and if check back to the bbl file, the "-" became fffd...

```
\name{labelname}{2}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=4d61c716006737e01dad3e296d8cb4b2}{Baker}
{B\bibinitperiod}{F.B.}{F\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=bbeb8c73c9f3f7bd033ecb2e8bbdab2d}
{Al\x{fffd}\x{fffd}\x{fffd}Karni}{A\bibinitperiod}{A}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
```

and the output of pdflatex will be

> Baker, F. & AlfffdfffdfffdKarni, A. (1991). A comparison of two procedures for
>   computing IRT equating coefficients. Journal of Educational Measurement, 28,
>   147–162.

rather than the original one as

> Baker, F. & Al-Karni, A. (1991). A comparison of two procedures for
>   computing IRT equating coefficients. Journal of Educational Measurement, 28,
>   147–162.

Is it a bug of biber or biblatex? And how to fix it?

Comment: Try to replace the dash by a normal dash: `-`. The dash in your file might be some weird unicode character that looks like a dash but isn't the normal one. (In fact, if you copy the character in `Al‐Karni` from your MWE and search for it on this page, you will only find that occurrence of the character; all the other dashes are different characters.)

Comment: shall I delete it? Or what should I do?

Comment: (The strange character is not that weird, it's a unicode HYPHEN. So totally the right kind of dash, except that with TeX you use normal ASCII "-".)

Comment: The reference was generated from Scopus and managed by Mendeley.

Comment: question about a similar problem: [LuaTeX won't end a line at Unicode emdash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149895/579)

Comment: xelatex or lualatex and biber have no problem with this. However, you just found a gap in biber's UTF-8 <-> TeX macro recoding table so I'll fix this in 1.9. Then you can just call biblatex with the "safeinputenc" option and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can either change the character in the `bib` file with a simple hyphen.

Here's a different strategy that might be better with automatically generated bib entries.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Baker,
author = {Baker, F. B. and Al‐Karni, A.},
journal = {Journal of Educational Measurement},
pages = {147--162},
title = {{A comparison of two procedures for computing IRT equating coefficients}},
url = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1745-3984.1991.tb00350.x/abstract},
volume = {28},
year = {1991}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % avoid strange translations by Biber
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{‐}{-} % the first is what's in Al‐Karni, the second is a normal hyphen

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Baker}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to have a self-contained example, use your own bib file.

[image]