# microtype won't work in theorem environment, using Times New Roman

Tags: xetex, amsthm, microtype

I'm using *microtype* package in my document. However, it won't fit to margin the text into the definition environment. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Discretionary]{Times New Roman}

%SECTIONS, THEOREMS,...
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}


\newenvironment{myproof}[1][Solución]{%
  \begin{proof}[#1]$ $\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{proof}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Retículo de filtros}
\section{Retículo de filtros}
        
    \begin{definition}
        Sea $L$ un retículo. Un conjunto no vacío $J \subseteq L$ es un \textbf{\textit{ideal}} —respectivamente un \textbf{\textit{filtro}}— si y sólo si
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
            \itemsep0em 
            \item Si $a,b \in J$, entonces $\sup\{a,b\} \in J$ —resp. $\text{ínf}\{a,b\} \in J$—.
            \item Si $a \in L$, $b \in J$ y $a \leqslant b$ —resp. $a \geq b$—, entonces $a \in J$.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{definition}
    \begin{myproof}[Demostración]
            
    \end{myproof}
\end{document}
```

Here the result
[image]

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: with a texlive 2021 xelatex I get  no overfull biox an [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6t9.png)

Comment: That's weird because I'm using texlive 2021 too

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get no break with xelatex, only with lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's what I expected but I got a break with both...

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with `microtype`, which you can verify by removing the package.

Comment: my image is generated with the original example, the question has been changed with a new example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XeLaTeX, a word immediately following `–` is never hyphenated. The issue so has nothing to do with the font or with `microtype`.

I suggest defining a command for these situations: thus you can add `\nobreak\hspace{0pt}` after the opening em-dash hidden in a `\mbox`, which will allow hyphenation in the following word, but won't allow that em-dash to appear at the end of a line.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%SECTIONS, THEOREMS,...
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}


\newenvironment{myproof}[1][Solución]{%
  \begin{proof}[#1]\mbox{}\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{proof}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\resp}[1]{\mbox{—}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}#1—}
\newcommand{\emphdef}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\section{Retículo de filtros}
        
\begin{definition}
Sea $L$ un retículo. Un conjunto no vacío $J \subseteq L$ es un 
\emphdef{ideal} \resp{respectivamente un \emphdef{filtro}} si y sólo si
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),itemsep=0pt]
  \item Si $a,b \in J$, entonces $\sup\{a,b\} \in J$ \resp{resp. $\text{ínf}\{a,b\} \in J$}.
  \item Si $a \in L$, $b \in J$ y $a \leqslant b$ \resp{resp. $a \geq b$}, entonces $a \in J$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\begin{myproof}[Demostración]
Whatever.            
\end{myproof}
\end{document}
```

I also added `\emphdef` so you can later change your mind about how to emphasize defined terms (boldface *and* italic is too much, in my opinion).

Note also `itemsep=0pt` as an option, rather than setting `\itemsep` directly. Better `\mbox{}` than the clumsy `$ $`.

[image]

The option `Ligatures=Discretionary` with Times New Roman does nothing else than produce warnings (at least on my system).

Some other suggestions. Times for text and Computer Modern for math don't really blend. Also `\text{ínf}` is not guaranteed to yield the desired result (it will be in italic if the current font is italic).

You can load `newtxmath` and change the `operators` font. Also `spanishoperators=all` will do the right thing.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\setdefaultlanguage[spanishoperators=all]{spanish}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%SECTIONS, THEOREMS,...
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}


\newenvironment{myproof}[1][Solución]{%
  \begin{proof}[#1]\mbox{}\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{proof}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\resp}[1]{\mbox{—}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}#1—}
\newcommand{\emphdef}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\section{Retículo de filtros}
        
\begin{definition}
Sea $L$ un retículo. Un conjunto no vacío $J \subseteq L$ es un 
\emphdef{ideal} \resp{respectivamente un \emphdef{filtro}} si y sólo si
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),itemsep=0pt]
  \item Si $a,b \in J$, entonces $\sup\{a,b\} \in J$ \resp{resp. $\inf\{a,b\} \in J$}.
  \item Si $a \in L$, $b \in J$ y $a \leqslant b$ \resp{resp. $a \geq b$}, entonces $a \in J$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\begin{myproof}[Demostración]
Whatever.            
\end{myproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my issue! As it was an MWE I didn't bother to include other libraries I'm using for math typesetting. I'm taking your advice on everything else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the — before “respectivamente.” Because XeLaTeX treats it as a proper em dash, it ends up turning off hyphenation for the word which follows it (note that the issue has nothing to do with microtype and will still happen without that package loaded). This is by design and is usually the preferred setting. If you want that word to break you need to put in a discretionary hyphen to indicate that a break is allowable.

LuaLaTeX, which by default has messed up parameters around — (so unlike pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX it will *not* break a line after an em-dash) ends up being willing to hyphenate there, which is usually not the preferred setting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the final sentence. For sure, I used LuaLaTeX to compile the code in my answer, and I can report that LuaLaTeX did *not* hyphenate "respetivamente" if it followed an emdash.

Comment: The "messed up" parameter you complain about here has nothing to do with it. This is not a hyphen but an emdash. Changing `\automatichyphenmode` wouldn't change the behaviour. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62800/2388

Comment: The problem is that LuaLaTeX treats — differently than --- unlike pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this works, but inserting `\hspace{0pt}` after `—` re-enables hyphenation of "respectivamente".

[image]

I would definitely also replace `\text{ínf}` with `\inf`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{definition}
Sea $L$ un retículo. Un conjunto no vacío $J \subseteq L$ es un 
\textbf{\textit{ideal}}—\hspace{0pt}respectivamente un 
\textbf{\textit{filtro}}—si y sólo si
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),noitemsep]    
   \item Si $a,b \in J$, entonces $\sup\{a,b\} \in J$—resp. 
         $\inf\{a,b\}\in J$.
   \item Si $a \in L$, $b \in J$ y $a \leqslant b$—resp. 
         $a \geq b$—, entonces $a \in J$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works because then the word no longer has an explicit hyphenchar appearing in its text. I'm pretty sure this is mentioned somewhere in *The TeXbook* but I can't find it right now.