# Drawing a path from a tikzmarknode to a node concisely and using the plus-sign line-to operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark, tikz-path

I'm editing a 50 pages long article in which I'd like to mark texts using `tikzmarknode` and then draw a path from it into a node like this:

[image]

I wrote this this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,draw]{surname}{\mbox{Kennedy}}\lipsum[1]

\vspace{25pt}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) -| ([shift={(-1.3,-5.2)}]surname.south west) -- ([shift={(0.5,-5.2)}]surname.south west) 
% \draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) -| (-1.3,-5.2) -- (1.8,0)  % That looks fine but it doesn' give the expected result
% \draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) -| (-1.3,-5.2) +- (1.8,0)  % That's intuitive but it doesn't  even compile
% \draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) -| ([shift={(-1.3,-5.2)}]surname.south west) -- (1.8,0)  % That still involves repetition  and doesn't give the expected output
node [right, draw]{\footnotesize John Fitzgerald Kennedy, the 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've managed to draw the path albeit with code repetitions. To eliminate them, I've rewritten the path, 3 of my rewrite  attempts are given in the code. None of them worked. One of them gave e.g. this output:

[image]

I've taken a look at the TikZ documentatiomn but it's hard to digest this specific information out of it. I've taken a look at this similar question [Telling TikZ to continue the previously-drawn path with a line-to operation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256883/telling-tikz-to-continue-the-previously-drawn-path-with-a-line-to-operation) but it doesn't fit the particular structure of my problem.

How to write that path code in the most concise manner? Rationale: I'll be using this code tens of times in the article I edit.

**Optional / Related Question** How to use the plus-sign line-to operation?  It might be documented somewhere but because it's a symbol with no name, it's not easy to identify it in the TikZ documentation or search for it on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is the following:

[image: path with --++ and |-++]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,draw]{surname}{\mbox{Kennedy}}\lipsum[1]

\vspace{25pt}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) --++ (-1.5,0) |-++ (1.5,-5) node [right, draw]{\footnotesize John Fitzgerald Kennedy, the 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Quick explanation

`--++ (-1.5,0)` means "draw from current point to the point 1.5cm on the left and place the current point on that location";

`|-++ (1.5,-5)` means "draw from current point to the point 1.5 cm on the right and 5cm below, but first drawing vertically then horizontally, and place the current point at this location".